# How can i display date and time in a field with date type

Tags: dynamic-programming, axapta, development-environment, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

How can i display the current date and time in a field with date type.
I can show the current date with today() but how can i display the current time.
Furthermore i want display these two in one field.

Thanks for every help.
Felix

Comment: Did you try `Now()` instead? Today only returns the date, Now returns current date and time.

Comment: yes, the function has not been declared

Answer (score 7):

I am afraid that is not possible as a field of type `date` holds just that - the date. Use type `utcdatetime` and the appropriate control `UtcDateTimeEdit` to show dates & times in one control.

To retrieve the current date & time you can call `DateTimeUtil::utcNow()` to which you may want to apply the local time zone via `DateTimeUtil::applyTimeZoneOffset`

Comment: Can you explane who i do that.

Comment: What exactly is unclear to you? Maybe you want to show some of your code etc. with which you have problems converting it to utcdatetime

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
utcDateTime _utcDateTime;
;
_utcDateTime = DateTimeUtil::getSystemDateTime();
```

Then you can extract separately the date and the time if you want.

Comment: Thanks for this idea, but i want show the date and the time in a field with date type.
Thus the types are incompatible.
I think I have to change the field again if I want to display both...

Comment: Try this to extract the date by date field, and time in str
utcDateTime _utcDateTime;    
    date _date;
    TimeOfDay  _hour;
    int  _min, _sec;
    str  _Hourstr;
    
    ;
    
    _utcDateTime = DateTimeUtil::getSystemDateTime();    
    _Date = DateTimeUtil::date(_utcDateTime); //Date
    _hour = DateTimeUtil::time(_utcDateTime);    
    _hour = _hour /60;
    _hour = _hour /60;
    _min = DateTimeUtil::minute(_utcDateTime);        
    _sec = DateTimeUtil::second(_utcDateTime);        
    _Hourstr  = int2str(_hour) + ":" + int2str(_min) + ":" + int2str(_Sec); //Hour